# Swift Package Manager and IBDesignable Error

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift-package-manager

I'm working on adding Swift Package Manager support to an existing iOS library that I have that already supports CocoaPods and Carthage. I was able to able to setup the `Package.swift` file and create the package and push those changes to the repo. It compiles fine in Xcode and builds fine on the command line.

The issue I'm having is when I add it as a dependency to a test application, the IBDesignable stuff won't compile, and errors with a `Build Failed` flag. The message states:

> The built product "" does not exist in the file system. Make sure your built products contains either an application or a framework product.

I have tried cleaning, deleting derived data, and removing/re-adding the package to the project.

My `Package.swift` file is as follows:

```swift
// swift-tools-version:5.3

import PackageDescription

let package = Package(
    name: "package_name",
    platforms: [
        .iOS(.v11)
    ],
    products: [
        .library(
            name: "package_name",
            targets: ["target_name"])
    ],
    targets: [
        .target(
            name: "target_name"
        )
    ])
```

Is there something I'm missing or a setting that needs to be set in order for it to function properly?

Thanks in advance for all the help.

Comment: I’m having the same issue. The error message says something about “appletvsimulator”, even though boith my app and the framework that contains the designables is iOS-only...

Comment: Just an update, I created a Feedback for this -> FB8991690. 

Apple responded with the following: 

`Thank you for contacting us. At this time, there isn't any new information available for this issue.  

We will do our best to keep you informed as new information becomes available. Please be sure to regularly check the seed and release notes for potential or related fixes that might affect this issue. 

We sincerely appreciate your patience and thank you for your support.`